# Why is child component getting mounted in advance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Here is my main Search component where I receive data using axios. I get the received data after checking through console.log

```
class Search extends Component {
 state = {
    hcpName: [],
    hcps: [],
    showTab: false,
    searchName: '',
    isLoading: false,
    page_id: 2,
    page_id_name: 1,
    hcp_id: 101,
    receivedData: [],
    nameData: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    let page_id = this.state.page_id;
    let hcp_id = this.state.hcp_id;
    console.log('state: ', this.state);
    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: page_id,
        hcp_id: hcp_id
    })
        .then((res) => {
            const dataRequest = res.data;
            console.log('State before loading data: ', this.state);
            console.log('received data', res.data);
            this.setState({ ...this.state, receivedData: res.data });
            console.log('State after loading data: ', this.state);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}


  render(){
   return(
     <div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" style={{ padding: 0 }}>
                    <div class="tabs-container-fluid">
                        <MidTabs />
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            {this.state.receivedData.length !== 0 && <Dashboard data={this.state.receivedData} />}
                            <SalesOverview />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

As you can see I have the Sales Overview component inside my Search component. I want the data for sales overview component to be fetched only after the user clicks on the Sales Overview tab. But in the current case, the data is getting fetched immediately after the Search component is mounted. Here is the code for the child component Sales Overview.

```
 class SalesOverview extends Component {

state = {
    monthly: false,
    quarterly: true,
    yearly: false,
    page_id: 4,
    hcp_id: 101,
    sales_overview_data: []
}


componentDidMount() {
    let page_id = this.state.page_id;
    let hcp_id = this.state.hcp_id;
    console.log('state: ', this.state);
    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: page_id,
        hcp_id: hcp_id
    })
        .then((res) => {
            const dataRequest = res.data;
            console.log('State before loading data in sales overview: ', this.state);
            console.log('received data inside sales overview', res.data);
            this.setState({ ...this.state, sales_overview_data: res.data });
            console.log('State after loading data in sales overview: ', this.state);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}



monthlyRangeClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ monthly: true, quarterly: false, yearly: false })
}

quarterlyRangeClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ monthly: false, quarterly: true, yearly: false })
}

yearlyRangeClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ monthly: false, quarterly: false, yearly: true })
}


render() {
   return(.....)
     }
```

Basically I'm getting the sales overview child component data(which I checked through console log) immediately after the application opens which I don't want. I want the axios request to be done only after the Sales Overview component gets mounted which I assume it mounts after the user clicks on the sales overview tab.

Here is a little screenshot of how the application looks like for a better understanding. As you can see, there's a separate tab for the sales overview section which is basically a component inside my code. Also, if anyone is having questions around why there's no code for Promotional Activity component, Engage with HCP, etc, well I have removed unnecessary code so that you don't have to look at a lot of code.

[image]

Comment: If you want to get the data only after the user clicks on the Sales Overview tab then you shouldn't be fetching the data in componentDidMount(). What you can do is fetch the data when the tab is clicked by setting an onclick event handler.

Comment: I think that makes sense, I'll try that.

Comment: But is there a way to place that component such that it doesn't get unconditionally mounted unless we want it to mount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Search render the `<SalesOverview />` component is being unconditionally included, so it will be mounted when Search is mounted and will therefore fetch the data.

Without knowing more about the output structure of your app, going just on what you have posted I'm guessing that the tab and the content are both in the SaleOverview component. In which case you need to add an state handler to know if the tab has been clicked and then fetch the data, not in componentDidMount

Comment: However, is there a way to use ComponentDidMount instead of the onClick Handler. You mentioned that Sales Overview is being unconditionally include but is there a way to place that component such that it doesn't get unconditionally mounted unless we want it to mount?